# MySQL Finding Substring Matches and Group by Match Full Word

Tags: mysql, sql, search, find, match

Working with MySQL and I can't find the right combination of terms for this expression.

Using a PHP user input variable in my statement, I need to find a partial substring match and group by the full match word

Taking example input *"#bea"* I want to find matches for *"#bea"* as a substring in full text posts, then group by and count the full word where it matches such as *"#beat"*, *"#beauty"*, *"#beast"*

With example posts in database

```
Testing Post #beat #beauty

Another test #beauty #beast

Testing #boom #beast
```

I want to search for a substring, example "#bea"

and have the output

```
Match   | Count
#beast  | 2
#beauty | 2
#beat   | 1
```

Can this be done with MySQL or am I better finding matches and counting full words using a PHP algorithm?

Comment: GROUP BY, LIKE, COUNT(), etc.

Comment: I can use LIKE and GROUP BY but this returns the full post, I'm looking for a way to only return the word in which the substring was found, not the full text post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.word `Match`, COUNT(B.sentence) `Count`
FROM 
(SELECT '#beast' word UNION ALL
SELECT '#beauty' word UNION ALL
SELECT '#beat' word) A LEFT JOIN Sentence B
ON INSTR(B.sentence,A.word)>0
GROUP BY A.word
ORDER BY  `Count` DESC, A.word;
```

See [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffc357/4) and [INSTR() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to find count of each word.

```
SELECT
sum(INSTR( '#beast' , TABLE.COL) > 0) '#beast',
sum(INSTR( '#beauty' , TABLE.COL) > 0) '#beauty'
FROM
TABLE
```

Then you can pivot table if needed;
[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)